# Dll works on server 2019, but not Windows 11

Tags: dll

I apologize for the vague nature of the question, but I am grasping at straws to figure anything out. I have two applications, Tradestation and Ninjatrader and a dll that allow one to talk to another. Using the latest version of Ninjatrader, the dll works on the Windows server 2019, but not on a Windows 11 desktop. Where should I look for an answer?